# Speech_recognition error on my raspberry pi4(Linux machine)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a speech recognition program on my raspberry pi4. I have done a lot of research and I have successfully reduced the line error to two lines.

My code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def get_input():
    # this for loop prints all avalable microphones and its index
    for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
        print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    print(r)
    mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)
    with mic as source:
        print(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""
        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: + " + str(e))
        return said

get_input()
```

The error:

> ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with the `speech_recognition` module, it is an error with `ALSA` - the Advanced Linux Subsystem for Audio. ALSA interfaces between the hardware and the RPi operating system - which I'm assuming is something Debian-ish like Raspbian.

You need to run `alsamixer` which should be installed by default, and use `alsamixer` to select the correct sound card, and microphone.

What is the output of `arecord -l`?